# React Native: The development server returned response error code:500

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, react-navigation

I am getting this error when running 'react-native run-android' after I installed React Navigation 6x. How can I solve this problem? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Tried ```npm install```?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, you are missing babel package.